# How to create dashed line in plotly R map type scattermapbox

Tags: r, plotly, mapbox

I need to make a dashed line in a plotly map (of type = 'scattermapbox').

I tried several possibilties in the `line=` option but with no avail.

```
plot_ly() %>%
  ## KOSOVO SERBIA BORDER ----------
  add_trace(
    type = 'scattermapbox',
    mode = 'markers+lines', # "markers+lines"
    lat = c(42.2628,42.343,42.6513,42.7009,42.6828,42.7294,42.7294,42.7487,42.8723,42.9085,43.0056,43.0165,43.1198,43.1461,43.2725,43.1926,43.1165,43.0287,42.9562,42.8871,42.8334,42.8334),
    lon = c(21.5869,21.5625, 21.7783, 21.7534, 21.66, 21.5717, 21.5717, 21.4095, 21.4351, 21.2683, 21.228, 21.1695, 21.1177, 20.9236, 20.8197, 20.6184, 20.6824, 20.6589, 20.506, 20.5121, 20.3529, 20.3529),
    marker = list(size = 0, color='green'),
    line=list(width=1, color='red', dash='dash', linetype='dash') # ! dash= and linetype= not working
  ) %>%
  layout(
    mapbox = list(
      style = "carto-positron",
      zoom = 6, center = list(lon=21, lat=43)
    )
  )
```

result:
[image]

I also tried to play with dot markers but the issue is that I really need a dashed look (for legal reasons) and this method doesn't work on different zoom levels because the markers scale up and become too big at `zoom=1`.

I started from this doc if this is useful to provide help: https://plotly.com/r/lines-on-mapbox/

Comment: do you _have_ to use plotly, or are you open to using [mapdeck](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/blob/master/R/map_layer_path.R#L21), which also uses mapbox, and has `dash` arguments?

Comment: @tospig I was thinking that without a solution I would abandon plotly and go with leaflet, but I would rather not throw all the efforts I put in my plotly map in the bin. My map is more complex than this bit, it is a chropleth of categorical values per country (which btw is also not supported by plotly but I solved that by hacking the color scale).

Comment: that is also possible in [mapdeck](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/layers.html#polygons)